# Force new users to go through animated tutorial before they post for the first time

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

Do not allow people to post the minute they created an account.

Let them ask the question but not allow them to post.

Let them stew for 30 minutes and force them through a nice animated tutorial on what they should do before they post and enforcing the fact that bad questions will not get an answer.

If they had a **Need to know!** basic rules introduction forced on them asking them at the end to check a box **I understand!** some might ask better questions and help the community instead of flooding the site with bad questions.

The presentation should be on a timer without the ability to skip and highlight the similar questions asked before that might give them the answer.

Also for the first next 9 posts they should have to check a box next to the first 5 of each similar questions before posting.

*I do not mean to be harsh, but the truth is I see more negative votes on questions then positive. It's like 90% of the time people give -1 to first questions.*

Comment: You *really* want to deter new users this much? That's not very welcoming and stopping new users joining isn't exactly the best way to keep a site growing and existing.

Comment: You created this meta account 9 minutes before asking a question. Would you have preferred to wait another 21 minutes?

Comment: *"I do not mean to be harsh, but the truth is I see more negative votes on questions then positive. It's like 90% of the time people give -1 to first questions."* **So what?** What's wrong with this situation? Downvotes are a healthy and vital part of the system. How are downvotes on *some* new questions worse than imposing a 30 minute delay on *all* new users?

Comment: Kid's play. I say just stop accepting new account registrations.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about you, but I wouldn't want to wait 30 minutes before even being able to ask a question.

That's one of the good things about SO: ask a question instantly with no annoying setup process or anything, just a simple signup that takes 5 minutes max. Then you can get answers in usually less than 10 minutes. The whole process is so simple that it usually only takes 5-10 minutes to solve your problem.

We want *more* new users, not less. Deterring the majority of users who aren't ridiculously patient is not a good thing.

Our current review process works great. Look at all of the things:

- First Posts review queue
- 125+ rep users can downvote
- 3k+ users can vote to close questions
- 10k+ users can vote to delete once closed for a while
- 20k+ users can vote to delete instantly
- Moderators can do even more
- Question is at the top of the active list, and many people can then see it
- Question ban in case of many many bad questions
- Need I go on?

I don't see anything wrong with how it is currently. A bad question can be removed within 10 minutes, and then the user who asked it can be taught how to ask better questions. It works, so why change it?

Comment: _"A bad question can be removed within 10 minutes"_ or [95 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805083/hi-can-anyone-help-me-with-this). The best I've ever seen is certainly less than 60 seconds, but I didn't favourite it unfortunately.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Wow... that's impressive `:D`

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards It's great that it was closed so quickly. But perhaps it shouldn't have been deleted just *two minutes* later, when it was possible, even if unlikely, the user could have improved it by showing what he'd tried.